# Serve out 'static' route with express with redirect and middleware

Tags: node.js, express

I am serving out a static url with express 4.0:

app.use('/static-route', express.static('./static'));

And that works great.

However I would like to redirect my users to a url with a query parameter if they hit that route.

ie /static-route -> /static-route?someQueryParam=hello

I would also like to include middleware for that static request.  As a concrete example I am using passport and would like to make sure the user is logged in to access that static content.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Do you want to redirect them instead of serving the requested static file, or only redirect if the query parameter is missing, or something else?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  The index.html that will get served from that static directory looks for a query parameter.  I would like to redirect to a url with the query parameter set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

app.use (and app.get etc . . .) doesn't take two parameters, the first parameter is the route (optional for use), then the rest are all middleware.

```
app.use('/static-route', function (req, res, next) {
  // validation
  // redirect
  // etc . . .
  next();
}, express.static('./static'));
```

Comment: For whatever reason app.use('/static-route', express.static('./static')); serves the index.html in the static directory.  However your solution with middleware just calling next I get a 404.  I verified the middleware is executed, and next() is called.

Comment: Seemed to be a bug in the express version I was running.  Upgraded to 4.10.6 and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

- Use global wilcard route[ app.use('/') ] for static content and
- Use specific routes [ app.get(/myroute), app.post('/anotherroute')] for dynamic processing using custom logic

```
//Serves resources from public folder 
app.use('/',express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

//Verify the complete directory path - especially slashes 
console.log('Static directory '+__dirname + '/public');

app.get('/list', function (req, res) {
    res.send('<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>'); });
```